# Missing authentication field in headers to store cookie expressjs

Tags: node.js, express, cookies

I'm trying to login with cookie JWT HTTPOnly, the problem is that the cookie comming with the response to the server, is comming in a field named 'cookie' and I would liked to have the cookie in a field named 'authorization' with a type 'Bearer' token. I'm using axios as client...

This is how the headers coming from my browser looks like...

```
{ host: 'localhost:8000',
  connection: 'keep-alive',
  accept: 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
  origin: 'http://localhost:8080',
  'user-agent':
   'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.169 Safari/537.36',
  referer: 'http://localhost:8080/allusers',
  'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
  'accept-language': 'pt-PT,pt;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7',
  cookie:
   'jwt=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpZCI6IjVkNzE2ODI4NjE4ZjllMTQzYzY2NjIwNSIsImlhdCI6MTU2ODEwNzkxMSwiZXhwIjoxNTcwNjk5OTExfQ.cq85nqtLlw4npP53_3x-YxhXvapsm9qXKgOH0RCkLIM' }
```

this is how a send my cookie JWT

```
     const token = jwt.sign({
           id: user._id
      },
        process.env.JWT_SECRET, {
        expiresIn: process.env.JWT_EXPIRES_IN
       }
      );

    const cookieOptions = {
        expires: new Date(
          Date.now() + process.env.JWT_COOKIE_EXPIRES_IN * 24 * 60 * 
       60 * 1000
        ),
        httpOnly: true
      };

      res.cookie('jwt', token, cookieOptions);
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of doing `res.cookie('jwt', token, cookieOptions);`
You could try using the standard response header.

You can set a header field to a value of your choosing:

```
res.set('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
```

Or set your own:

```
res.set(field, [value]);
```

I hope this helps!

Also maybe let the server make JWT keys in the future. That is how most people do it.
A good read is: [The Hard Parts of JWT Security Nobody Talks About](https://www.pingidentity.com/en/company/blog/posts/2019/jwt-security-nobody-talks-about.html)